# How to access prefix S3 while auto record with Amazon IVS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ivs

Today I tried to use Amazon Interactive Video Service with auto record to an Amazon S3 bucket. The problem is that after live streaming ended I want to get the video recorded in S3. I follow the documentation then I get path/prefix like below:

```
/ivs/v1/<aws_account_id>/<channel_id>/<year>/<month>/<day>/<hours>/<minutes>/<recording_id>
```

At the path I can find in response json except

```
<recording_id>
```

FYI the `recording_id` created when I start live streaming, but I cannot get a response. So how can I get the recording id with response JSON to access the path of video recorded in S3?

Answer (score 0):

According to the AWS IVS documentation, you'll have to subscribe to the IVS Record State Change event. (see [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ivs/latest/userguide/eventbridge.html#eventbridge-examples-recording-state-change))

In the event data, there's a key called **recording_s3_key_prefix** that will be in the following format:

"recording_s3_key_prefix": "ivs/v1/123456789012/AbCdef1G2hij/2020/6/23/20/12/j8Z9O91ndcVs"

You'll be able to get the full path from there or if you just want the recording_id you may extract it from this key as well.